# DPDK testpmd minimal traffic

Tags: dpdk

I have setup a DPDK 17 version testpmd setup. I have two high end servers which have two NIC mapped using a physical direct connection. The issue is that when i try and send traffic from one server to another using testpmd, it either does not send traffic or sends very small number of packets. I have checked multiple documentations and nothing seems to work. My configuration also seems correct.

What am i doing wrong? Please help.

[image]

Comment: please provide the command line arguments used to run testpmd and also the output to dpdk-devbind --status. It seems you only have one port mapped and that it supposed to use 2 ports (receiving traffic from one port and forwarding it on the other)

Comment: you are right. I launched testpmd on the other server as well and then i could see sufficient traffic,

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces similar issues, it is important that both servers have testpmd running and correct NICs bound to DPDK.